# Android - ImageButton positioning to bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, imageview, imagebutton

OK. Well, although I use this site a lot, this is actually my first question.

Although I have many years experience in programming using Visual Studio, I have recently started to program for Android (using Android Studio) and I'm stuck on image positioning.

What I have is an image in an ImageView which automatically scales (as you would expect) to the orientation of the screen and super imposed on this are ImageButtons.

Currently, I am using automatic positioning to the ImageView for the ImageButtons but what I'm after is to position the ImageButtons exactly to the upper right corner of the (scaled) image, no matter it's size or position.

I can get the (default) size of the image but what I need to retrieve is the scaled size and x:y co-ordinates and then adjust setTop() and setRight() of the ImageButton accordingly.

I have read loads of examples on here but I don't seem to make any of them do what I'm looking for. Is there a simple method for getting the size / position of the displayed / scaled image (where actual image pixels are displayed), or is this something I would have to manually do by creating my own function?

Thanks in advance.

Correct Landscape:

[image]

Incorrect Landscape:

[image]

Correct Portrait:

[image]

Incorrect Portrait:

[image]

Comment: Please add a link to a picture of what you are after, so we can see how to get you there. I think it can be achieved by using a layout file (xml) and no code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've had to do it via external web page as I don't have enough rep as yet to post images.

Comment: I added the pictures to your question and removed the text part ("I don't have reputation, so I created a WebPage").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the problem... but i'll try to make and answer for that.

when you use imageView you can set this attributes

```
scaleType="fitXY"
adjustBounds="true"
```

That will center your image view and resize to XY if is necessary. But please remember that you need to use **src=""** and not **setbackground** in the image view.

Well with this clear we'll proceed with RelativeLayout

Make a parent for example a FrameLayout, inside make a relative layout this (nesting is not necessary but for now we'll use it).

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i don't test it but thats the main idea.

Comment: This won't work. It will align the imageButton with the Parent's top right corner. But the OP wants to align it with the ImageView's...

Comment: Thank you! All I needed to do was the "adjustViewBounds" which I had never even thought about; but now I know... Thanks again!